# ping на java из командной строки. проблема с кодировкой

Tags: java, кодировка, cmd

Есть такой код:

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PingIP {

 public static void runSystemCommand(String command) {

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String s = "";
        // reading output stream of the command
        while ((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String ip = "google.com";
    runSystemCommand("ping " + ip);

}

}
```

Сохранял файл в разных кодировках из vs studio code. Сохранение в кириллице 1251 на скриншоте. Как поправить кодировку? Cmd выводит ответы пинга на русском языке по умолчанию. Может можно на англ поменять, но это на втором плане, хотелось бы на русском.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы использовали конструктор InputStreamReader, который принимает 2ым параметром Charset?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));`, как и подсказывает Andrey Bystrov

Comment: @AndrewBystrow сплошные знаки вопроса вместо русских символов

Comment: @MrFylypenko сплошные знаки вопроса вместо русских символов

Comment: Попробовал различные комбинации кодировок и кодировок при сохранении - без резульата

Comment: Лучше посмотрите в настройках командной строки(Вашей консоли) кодировку по умолчанию, и попробуйте поменять кодировку на ютф-8, и напишите помогли или нет.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Программы, которые рассчитаны на использование в Windows в консольном режиме, по историческим причинам используют для вывода кодировку CP866, которая применялась в DOS. Java считает, что строки должны содержать Unicode. Иными словами, поток, который вы получаете от процесса p, содержит CP866, а вы обращаетесь с ним так, как будто он содержит Unicode.
Открывайте поток вот так:

```
  BufferedReader inputStream = 
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          p.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("CP866")));
```

и всё будет в порядке.

Comment: Сработало даже вот так new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), "CP866"));

Comment: Есть разница между?

Comment: Да нет, в принципе. Это просто разные перегруженные версии конструктора, один принимает `String` с именем кодировки в качестве аргумента (как в вашем примере), а другой - саму кодировку (как в моем примере). Первый вариант лаконичнее, но второй вариант позволяет использовать кодировку, полученную откуда-то, даже не зная ее имени. По результату в данном случае они эквивалентны.

Comment: @спасибо вам вам

Comment: Хотя это и не относиться напрямую к вопросу, у меня такие замечания: 1). Сделать определение кодировки в зависимости от системы. Java - мультиплатформенная среда, и если Вы запустите этот код в Linux, опять получите нечитаемые символы; 2). Если Вы используете Java 7+, используйте try-with-resources при работе с потоками, это позволит избежать утечки ресурсов и корректно закроет потоки